# Bones moving wrong part of mesh

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

[image]
I have a simple low poly mesh that I have created and rigged.

[image]

However, when i try to move a bone in the arm area, the hip moves along with it. 
[image]

As you can see the area is all blue so Im extremely confused as to how this is possible, Im open to all answers.

Comment: I've found that sometimes weights get assigned without colors, which is weird, I know. Maybe try posing the character a bit and then try removing weights from the bits that don't seem to be weighted but are still being affected?

Comment: When you are moving a bone, all child bones move as well. Check, if the hip isn't assigned to one of them.

Comment: It doesn't just happen at the arm anymore it happens at basically every bone I use .